# Validar Regex con jQuery

Tags: jquery, regex, validación

estoy intentando validar los strings de varios inputs con jQuery tomando su atributos pattern, esto con el propósito de si los valores son validos cambiar estilos y permitir enviar el formulario.

Como ejemplo si ponemos "Carlos" debería ser valido y si ingresamos "Carlos." debiera ser invalido, sin embargo al hacer la prueba siempre me da el alert("valid").

Me parece que todo esta correcto pero alguien me da una mano para encontrar el error

```
<div class="wrapInput">
    <label for="example">Usuario</label>
    <div class="inputItem">
        <input type="text" name="example" minlength="10" maxlength="30" pattern="[a-zA-ZàáâäãåąčćęèéêëėįìíîïłńòóôöõøùúûüųūÿýżźñçčšžÀÁÂÄÃÅĄĆČĖĘÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏĮŁŃÒÓÔÖÕØÙÚÛÜŲŪŸÝŻŹÑßÇŒÆČŠŽ∂ð0-9 ,'-]+" required />
        <i class="icon-contact"></i>
    </div>        
</div>


$('.inputItem').on('focusout', 'input',function() {

var typeValue = $(this).attr('type');
var boxContainer = $(this).closest('div.wrapInput');
var inputValue = $(this).val();
var patternInput = new RegExp( $(this).attr('pattern') );

if(inputValue != ''){
    if(!inputValue.match(patternInput)){
        alert('invalid');
    
        boxContainer.removeClass('inputValid');
        boxContainer.addClass('inputInvalid');
    } else {
        alert('valid');
        boxContainer.removeClass('inputInvalid');
        boxContainer.addClass('inputValid');
        sendValid = true;
    }
}

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu problema es que estás diciendo, "si la cadena contiene uno o más caracteres de los que hay entre corchetes" es válida, por tanto el resultado de tu expresión regular validará una gran cantidad de cadenas y muchas que no quieres que se validen (como te está ocurriendo).

Deberías modificar tu expresión regular por:

```
^[a-zA-ZàáâäãåąčćęèéêëėįìíîïłńòóôöõøùúûüųūÿýżźñçčšžÀÁÂÄÃÅĄĆČĖĘÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏĮŁŃÒÓÔÖÕØÙÚÛÜŲŪŸÝŻŹÑßÇŒÆČŠŽ∂ð0-9 ,'-]+$
```

Simplemente he añadido un `^` al inicio, se traduce como "tiene que empezar con".

Y al final de la expresión regular un `$` que se traduce por "la cadena termina con".

Comment: Excelente Iromeraj, funciono totalmente, muchas gracias por la orientación